# Adding multiple rows into ListView and saving into SimpleAdapter without deletion

Tags: android, arrays, button, android-listview, simpleadapter

I have created a button called `save todo` which will take data inputted into an `EditText` and a `Spinner` and save them onto a `SimpleAdapter` `Array` and display them onto a `ListView` in another Activity called `MainActivity`. This works fine only for one time and then if I enter new information and press the button, it will replace the last saved data with the new one. I would like to make it so that it will save all the data inputted and not replace old data with the new that way the `ListView` would fill up with all the data that was entered.

MainActivity.java

//Here is where I have the `ListView` defined along with a static method that the Add_Item.java will use to populate it with rows

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//variables
    static ListView MainList;
    Button ItemButton;
    SimpleAdapter ListAdapt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//define variables
        ItemButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        MainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

//onclick
        ItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), Add_Item.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });

    }

    public static ListView getMainList(){
        return MainList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

//Add_Item.java 
//this is where you will find the arrays storing the data along with the button

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Add_Item extends ActionBarActivity {
//variables
    EditText TaskNameET, DateTimeET;
    Spinner SpinType;
    Button SaveTodo;
    String SpinnerOptions[] = {"OptionOne", "OptionTwo", "OptionThree"};
    SimpleAdapter ListAdapt;

//call mainactivity class
    //MainActivity Main = new MainActivity(); 

//declare arraylist and HashMap
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__item);

//define vars
        TaskNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TaskNameET);
        DateTimeET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        SpinType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        SaveTodo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

//initialize mylist and map 
        mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();


//SimpleAdapter 
        ListAdapt = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.row, new String[] {"columnone", "columntwo", "columnthree"}, new int[] {R.id.columnone, R.id.columntwo, R.id.columnthree});

//adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> ard=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, SpinnerOptions);
        SpinType.setAdapter(ard);

//onclick todobutton
        SaveTodo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("columnone", Add_Item.this.TaskNameET.getText().toString());
                map.put("columntwo", Add_Item.this.SpinType.getSelectedItem().toString());
                map.put("columnthree", Add_Item.this.DateTimeET.getText().toString());
                mylist.add(map);
                MainActivity.getMainList().setAdapter(ListAdapt);
                Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add__item, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`put` method on `HashMap` Maps the specified key to the specified value. If specified key is already present then it will update value for specified key.

As you are adding same object in `ArrayList`. Your `ArrayList` will have two entries of same object with modified value.

Replace your `onClick` method as below.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("columnone", Add_Item.this.TaskNameET.getText().toString());
    map.put("columntwo", Add_Item.this.SpinType.getSelectedItem().toString());
    map.put("columnthree", Add_Item.this.DateTimeET.getText().toString());
    mylist.add(map);
    System.out.println(mylist);
    MainActivity.getMainList().setAdapter(ListAdapt);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

*Case 1:*

If you are saving this data some where in device and showing in each launch.

As you want `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist` to be persistent across each save operation.
Don't use `mylist` Save your Items in database. And in `onCreate` of your `Add_Item` Activity read Data from your database and populate your Adapter. Also add `onActivityResult` method in your `MainActivity` and get data from database and and update `ArrayAdapter` data and call `notifyDataSetChanged` method to make invalidate your `ArrayAdapter` of your `MainActivity`.

*Case 2:*

If you don't want data to be persistent across application sessions. then create `Data` model class of your data like.

```
public class Data implements Serializable{
    String columnone;
    String columntwo;
    String columnthree;


    public Data(String columnone, String columntwo, String columnthree) {
        this.columnone = columnone;
        this.columntwo = columntwo;
        this.columnthree = columnthree;
    }

    public String getColumnone() {
        return columnone;
    }

    public String getColumntwo() {
        return columntwo;
    }

    public String getColumnthree() {
        return columnthree;
    }
}
```

Create `Data` object on click of `SaveTodo` button of your `Add_Item` Activity and pass this object to `MainActivity` through bundle.

Maintain `ArrayList<Data>` in `MainActivity`. In `onActivityResult` method of your `MainActivity` retrieve passed data object and add it to `ArrayList`.
Also while starting `Add_Item` iterate over your `ArrayList` and pass each data object to to `Add_Item` Activity and in `onCreate` method of your `Add_Item` activity get all the data objects from bundle and populate your ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Could you show a code example please? I don't fully understand what you mean by creating a second HashMap.

Comment: Hello, I have another problem using this method. Now when I add the new row it will save. Then when I click the add_task Button that will take me to the to the Add_Item activity to add a new row using the button, it will delete the previous row and add the newest one. I would like to keep all the rows that have been added

Comment: It isnt saving the rows if I add an intent that goes back to the MainActivity, I will repost the new code.

Comment: What is a better approach?

Comment: Hello, could you go into more detail on case 2? I don't fully understand the technical lingo, more code examples would help a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: I understand you mean `    DataStorage data = new DataStorage(Add_Item.this.TaskNameET.getText().toString(), Add_Item.this.SpinType.getSelectedItem().toString(), Add_Item.this.DateTimeET.getText().toString());
` but then to create an Arraylist<Data> into mainactivity does what exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63224/discussion-between-kalpesh-patel-and-ssj3goku878).